# no entiendo el uso de flag en C para salir de un bucle

Tags: c, bucles

me encuentro en mi tercera semana en la U y avanzamos en el uso del flag para salir de un loop, pero la verdad no entiendo. Dejo abajo el código por si me pudieran ayudar se agradece mucho la ayuda.

```
int i, n, sum = 0, keepGoing = 1;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// A while loop that uses a flag to leave early. The flag
// becomes negative if a negative value is read or
// if the sum of the values exceeds 1000. The loop
// reads a maximum of 10 values.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
i = 0;
while (i < 10 && keepGoing == 1)
{
    printf("Enter up to 10 numbers (0 to stop): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    sum += n;
    keepGoing = n != 0 && sum < 1000;
    i++;
}
printf("The first sum=%d\n", sum);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Use an if nested inside a loop to sum the 
// absolute values of some numbers.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
sum = 0;
printf("Enter a number(0 to stop): ");
scanf("%d", &n);
while (n > 0)
{
    if (n > 0) sum += n;
    else sum += -n;
}
printf("The second sum=%d\n", sum);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: los bucles estan hechos para repetir el codigo que esta dentro de ellos la veces que sea necesario o hasta que se alcance un limite, normalmente los bucles tiene condicionales como:

Comment: `(n>0)` quiere decir que siempre que `n` sea mayor que 0, entonces para salir de ese bucle tienes que hacer algo para que `n` cambie... entonces `n` es un flag.

Comment: imagina que el valor de `n` inicial es 10, por si solo jamas cambiara, entonces, dentro del bucle tienes que hacer alguna operacion matematica para que llegue a 0, entonces puedes hacer algo como `n=n-1;` esto provocara que cada vez que pase a `n` se le reste 1

Comment: cuando `n` llegue a 0, ya no se cumplira la condicion del bucle y este se saldra del bucle.

Comment: hay otras formas mas especificas por ejemplo colocar dentro un if y hacer los cambios desde hay

Comment: Al parecer le llaman **flag** a introducir una nueva variable en la condición con el propósito de terminar el ciclo antes. No es la única manera de hacerlo, podrías hacer que la variable de iteración deje de cumplir la condición. En el primer `while` con establecer `i` en 10 o más la condición ya no se cumple. Aunque la legibilidad de este método es cuestionable. También existe la instrucción `break`, que interrumpe el ciclo inmediatamente.